# Why is REPEATED incompatible with REQUIRED?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In `model.py` line 862 you state that `'repeated is incompatible with required...'`.

Why is this so?

Is the only way to ensure that someone *must* assign a not-None list to an `ndb.Property` by using some kind of `_pre_put_hook()` magic?

Comment: This is not a duplicate... the devil is in the details.